# Will an SSD keep a computer from slowing down over time?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, speed, desktop-computer

Will a SSD keep a computer from slowing down over usage compared to a computer with a mechanical hard drive?

Comment: The reason your computer "becomes slow" has nothing to do with it being a mechanic drive or a SSD

Comment: @Ramhound doesn't it have something to do with defragmentation?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but could whoever downvoted me explain why? I haven't been using this site for too long and I would appreciate any tips!

Comment: - No;  Modern versions of Windows defrag your mechanical HDD daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the device will be fast because the fragmentation of files has no real negative impacts on SSDs in comparison to mechanical HDDs.

Since I use a SSD I never had slowness because of drive activity, only when the CPU was busy. On most systems the slow HDD is the largest bottleneck and replacing the HDD with a SSD also makes older Core2Duo systems fast again.